# Xlsxwriter different formats to different cells in same column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a problem when setting the format for different cells. I have two dataframes that contains numbers that should be shown in different formats. I have created a simple example to show my problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

frame1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)),  columns=list('ABCD'))

#want to show this frame as percentage in Excel later
frame2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)),    columns=list('EFGH'))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

frame1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol= 0, startrow= 0)

frame2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol= 0, startrow = (2 + len(frame1)))

writer.save()
```

This code produces this Excel Sheet:

[image: Shows output]

Now the problem is that I for instance might want to set the cells marked in yellow as % or as some other format. I know I can set the format on a whole column or a row, but I have not been able to solve how I can set the format for just some specific cells. I guess there is some really easy solutions to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column format in Excel applies to the entire column and can only be overridden by a row format or a cell format.

So you would need to apply a cell format to the cells that you wanted to format differently and that isn't possible with the Pandas interface.

An alternative could be to use a conditional format for the range of cells you are interested in. See for example [this Pandas program](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_conditional.html) from the XlsxWriter docs.

Comment: Tanks for the help, I am surprised that there isn't a simpler solution for this, but using the conditional_format works ok.

Answer (score 3):

The work-around would be using `conditional_format`, as mentioned by @jmcnamara, you just apply `{'type': 'top','value': str(f2rows),'format': format1}`, where `f2rows` is the number of rows of your dataframe and the `format1` is the format you would like to apply.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

frame1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)),  columns=list('ABCD'))

#want to show this frame as percentage in Excel later
frame2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)),    columns=list('EFGH'))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

frame1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol= 0, startrow= 0)

frame2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol= 0, startrow = (2 + len(frame1)))

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

f2rows = frame2.shape[0]
startR = 4 + len(frame1)
endR = startR + f2rows -1

# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFFF00',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

worksheet.conditional_format('C{}:C{}'.format(startR, endR), {'type': 'top',
                                           'value': str(f2rows),
                                           'format': format1})

worksheet.conditional_format('E{}:E{}'.format(startR, endR), {'type': 'top',
                                           'value': str(f2rows),
                                           'format': format1})

writer.save()
```